# how to change the value of a boolean after clicking a button in symfony

Tags: symfony, boolean

Here I have in my database an entity validateRdv which is a boolean, which I initialized the value to zero when the patient makes an appointment with a doctor. After the doctor must approve the appointment by clicking the approve button. And when the doctor clicks the button approve I want the value of the Boolean validateRdv be set to 1 and send an email to the patient to whom he approved the appointment. With my controller, I tried to change the value of the validateRdV attribute but I can not do it.
Maybe it's me who does it wrong. If anyone can help me

**Controller**

```
  public function approuverRdvAction(Request $request)
{
    // $id = $request->query->get('id');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repos = $em->getRepository("DoctixFrontBundle:Booking");
    $bookings = $repos->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->query->get("idBooking")));

    $booking = new Booking();
    $booking = $bookings;
    $booking->setValiderRdv();

    $em->persist($booking);
    $em->flush();

    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Votre Rdv est approuvé par le médecin'))
        ->setFrom("medmamtest@gmail.com")
        ->setTo($bookings->getPatient()->getUser()->getUsername())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'Emails/confirmation.html.twig',
                array('name' => 'Cher(s)')
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);

    return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:bookingConfirm.html.twig', array(
            'bookings' => $bookings
    ));
}
```

With that I have as error : **Call to a member function setValiderRdv() on null**

**Entity**

```
  <?php

  namespace Doctix\FrontBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**  
  * Booking
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="booking")
 * 


   class Booking
 {
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
 private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 *@ORM\Column(name="date_rdv", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $dateRdv;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 *@ORM\Column(name="heure_rdv", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $heureRdv;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 *@ORM\Column(name="valider_rdv", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $validerRdv;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $medecin;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctix\PatientBundle\Entity\Patient")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $patient;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set dateRdv
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateRdv
 *
 * @return Booking
 */
public function setDateRdv($dateRdv)
{
    $this->dateRdv = $dateRdv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateRdv
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateRdv()
{
    return $this->dateRdv;
}

/**
 * Set heureRdv
 *
 * @param \DateTime $heureRdv
 *
 * @return Booking
 */
public function setHeureRdv($heureRdv)
{
    $this->heureRdv = $heureRdv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get heureRdv
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getHeureRdv()
{
    return $this->heureRdv;
}

/**
 * Set validerRdv
 *
 * @param boolean $validerRdv
 *
 * @return Booking
 */
public function setValiderRdv($validerRdv)
{
    $this->validerRdv = $validerRdv;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get validerRdv
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getValiderRdv()
{
    return $this->validerRdv;
}


 /**
 * Set medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 * @return Booking
 */
public function setMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{
    $this->medecin = $medecin;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get medecin
 *
 * @return \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin 
 */
public function getMedecin()
{
    return $this->medecin;
}

 /**
 * Set patient
 *
 * @param \Doctix\PatientBundle\Entity\Patient $patient
 * @return Booking
 */
public function setPatient(\Doctix\PatientBundle\Entity\Patient $patient)
{
    $this->patient = $patient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get patient
 *
 * @return \Doctix\PatientBundle\Entity\Patient 
 */
public function getPatient()
{
    return $this->patient;
}
```

}

**Routing**

```
 medecin_booking_approuver:
     path: /medecin/booking/approuver
     defaults: { _controller: DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:approuverRdv}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your route definition to `approuverRdvAction` please ?

Comment: @Mcsky, it's done.

Comment: Feel free to ask if something isn't clear, or approve the answer ;)

Comment: @Mcsky, everything is clear. You clarified the situation with your explanation. one point I wanted to ask you is if I can use the same technique to cancel an appointment? If canceling an appointment is the same as refusing an appointment? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "is the same"? For me, it depends on your business logic. Do you have to do the difference between canceling and refusing an appointment ? If yes, implement it with boolean flags OR with a `status`

Comment: @Mcsky, What I mean is if there is a difference between canceling an appointment and refusing an appointment. For me, canceling an appointment means that the doctor is no longer available at this time. So this appointment will no longer be available and will be deleted from the database

Comment: It depend of your business logic, I can't help you on that ^^' I suggest you this doctrine extensions http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html 
You could keep canceled/refused rows in database (for monitoring purpose) but doctrine won't return you theses rows anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define that your route wait a specific parameter `id`, almost the same as a placeholder.

```
medecin_booking_approuver:
     path: /medecin/booking/{id}/approuver
     defaults: { _controller: DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:approuverRdv}
```

After that you just have to `typehint` your action with Booking class.
Symfony (thank to [param converter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter)) will retrieve from the database the booking entity of the id in the url.

```
public function approuverRdvAction(Request $request, Booking $booking)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $booking->acceptRdv();

    $em->flush();

    $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Votre Rdv est approuvé par le médecin'))
        ->setFrom("medmamtest@gmail.com")
        ->setTo($booking->getPatient()->getUser()->getUsername())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'Emails/confirmation.html.twig',
                array('name' => 'Cher(s)')
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);

    return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:bookingConfirm.html.twig', array(
            'bookings' => $booking
    ));
}
```

I suggest you do some improvements in your entity

```
   class Booking
 {
    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var \DateTime
    *
    *@ORM\Column(name="date_rdv", type="datetime")
    */
    private $dateRdv;

    /**
    * @var bool
    *
    *@ORM\Column(name="valider_rdv", type="boolean")
    */
    private $validerRdv;

    public function __constructor() {
        $this->validerRdv = false;
    }

    /**
    * The medecin accept the booking
    * @return Booking
    */
    public function acceptRdv()
    {
        $this->validerRdv = true;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * The medecin refuse the booking
    * Add this method only if it's possible to refuse a Rdv after accept it
    * @return Booking
    */
    public function refuseRdv() 
    {
        $this->validerRdv = false;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Do the medecin accepted the booking ?
    * @return bool
    */
    public function isValiderRdv()
    {
        return $this->validerRdv;
    }

    // ..................... OTHER FIELDS AND GETTER/SETTER ...............
}
```

Comment: thank you for your proposal.
I would like a bit of clarification on the second suggestion. Should this method implement it in my controller or in my entity? And if so, something like this : public function validateRdv () {return true; }

Comment: now I'm sure that the property validerRdv can not be nullable. and for the date and time it was a design error that I'm going to fix, but I was planning to finish with this feature there.

Comment: I added the example of the entity. See your entity like a dark box containing your data. You want to change your data only by known ways, and for that, you create public methods that can be called `on` your entity from elsewhere. In your previous version for example, it's possible to do `$booking->setValiderRdv('Hello world')` without error unless the update query to database is launched.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to say that you don't need to instantiate a new Booking to overwrite it because findOneBy() will return you an instance of that object.
About the problem, it seems that you're not getting your "idBooking" right because findOneBy() can't find an object with that ID, so I suggest you to find out the value that you're getting.
Also remember that setValiderRdv() is expecting a parameter (that must be a boolean), so that line must be:

```
$booking->setValiderRdv(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: regarding the problem, I want the approve button to validate only the appointment to which it is linked, that's why I did the findOneBy (idBooking).what do you suggest to me @J.Almandos

Comment: Regarding your suggest to put true, I have the same error with your suggest.